# Error looking up ${email.jndi.lookup.binding} in JNDI

Tags: java, jboss6.x

Working with JBoss eap 6.4.12

Getting error:

> Error looking up ${email.jndi.lookup.binding} in JNDI

Mapping this JNDI name in my java class:

```
@Resource(mappedName = "${email.jndi.lookup.binding}")
    private Session session;
```

I define this property in my build properties:

```
email.jndi.lookup.binding=java:/jboss/mail/Default
```

[image: JNDI name in JBoss console is displaying as java:jboss/mail/Default] (removing `\` after `:` in my build properties definition doesn't make a difference)

This is happened before to me on another project, in which changing the `annotation property replacement` property to true worked. But not this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up just adding a local bean

```
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class DefaultEmailManager  {

    public static final String JNDI_NAME = "java:jboss/mail/Default";

}
```

Then where I create my `Session` object:

```
private Session session;

try {
   InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
   session = (Session)ic.lookup(DefaultEmailManager.JNDI_NAME);

} catch (NamingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```